# How can track the provisioning process if we use SuiteBilling?

Tags: netsuite

We use NetSuite to sell SaaS subscriptions.

In Contract Renewals we use item fulfillments to track the provisioning process.

Now we are thinking about to migrate to SuiteBilling. However, in subscription items the Can Be Fulfilled/Received box must be unchecked. How can track the provisioning process if we use SuiteBilling?

Answer (score 0):

There is a transaction called a "Change Order" and the type is "Activate".  That will commence the billing stream.